# Screensaver changes images too quickly – is there a way to adjust it?

Tags: macos, preferences, screensaver

I like to display my own images using the Mac OS X screensaver, but it seems that Mountain Lion has shortened the duration for which each image is displayed. The duration is too short for my tastes – that is, the screensaver changes images too quickly. I searched online but could not find an explanation of how to change the refresh rate; I also looked inside the likely preferences files (`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist` and `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.preference.desktopscreeneffect.plist`) and none of the properties there appear relevant.

*Is* there a way to change the rate at which images are shown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution!

I followed these instructions and it worked for me!
http://wiki.daveking.com/index.php?title=Change_The_Slide_Duration_In_Screensaver_%22Ken_Burns%22_Slideshow

Comment: I can confirm this works for the "Classic" effect as well. Thank you for finding this and posting the answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is down right now. Could you reproduce the answer here?

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo Oops, I'm sorry, I never checked back here and didn't see your request until now. The gist of the answer is that you need to modify the integer value of the field `JustASlide`/`mainDuration` in the file `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Slideshows.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Content/EffectDescriptions.plist`. The units are seconds, and the default value is 3.  Note that you will also need to change the permissions on the file and the folder before being able to edit the file.

Comment: @mhucka the first entry of mainDuration is used in some kind of formula and used as variable.

`@ABCDEFGHGJKPQGQSde_needsRandomSeed[orientation_needsPanoInformationYclassNameWpresets]effectVersion_phaseInDurationZisNative3D_phaseOutDuration^imageInputInfo\mainDuration]numberOfTexts`

There is no mainDuration followed by integer in a whole file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @JohnnyFive Is this is on OS X 10.8? This answer probably does not apply to any other version of macOS....

Comment: @mhucka it was 10.14 mojave

Comment: @JohnnyFive I'm afraid I can't help with 10.14, as I'm still running 10.13. Maybe someone else will be able to answer.

Answer (score 2):

this does not work on MacOS Ventura.

The plist file sits now on the read-only system partition. :(

However someone on MacRumors recommended ArtSaver.
Which comes as an app or a Mac screensaver.

I downloaded and installed this and it works as expected.

https://user.informatik.uni-bremen.de/zach/software/ArtSaver/index.html

It has a lot of options, including slide duration:

[image]

Comment: This is going to be the answer going forward with the operating system sealing the contents of this specific default. Well done